process "/bin/sh -c npm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
Please help me solve this problem
I'm newbie and try to learning Docker and K8s
I try many other version of node:20.14.0-alpine3.20, alpine, 3.20,...... But all of this fail
So please help me solve it with basic way.
Thank you very much.
C:\Users\pvdat\simpleweb_philip>docker build .
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                                                                  docker:default
[+] Building 5.7s (5/5) FINISHED                                                                                                                         docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                               0.2s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 128B                                                                                                                               0.1s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                  0.2s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                    0.1s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:20.14.0-alpine3.20                                                                                         1.2s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/node:20.14.0-alpine3.20@sha256:66c7d989b6dabba6b4305b88f40912679aebd9f387a5b16ffa76dfb9ae90b060                            0.0s
 => ERROR [2/2] RUN npm install                                                                                                                                    4.2s
------
 > [2/2] RUN npm install:
4.088 npm error Tracker "idealTree" already exists
4.107
4.108 npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-06-08T10_48_36_021Z-debug-0.log
------
Dockerfile:4
--------------------
   2 |     FROM node:20.14.0-alpine3.20
   3 |
   4 | >>> RUN npm install
   5 |
   6 |     CMD ["npm","start"]
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

I tried to change lots of other version such as
FROM node:20.14.0-alpine3.20
FROM node:20.14.0-alpine
FROM node:20-alpine3.20

But all of this fail.
And I expect that npm install can install successfully.

Here is the source code that I use

FROM node:20.14.0-alpine3.20
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm","start"]

Is that your entire Dockerfile?  (Please [edit] it into the question, rather than trying to include it as a comment.)  You don't seem to COPY package*.json into the image, so npm install doesn't know what to do.

Hi, please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Does this help? npm ERR! Tracker "idealTree" already exists while creating the Docker image for Node project

Thank you very much. I solved it by using WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY ./ ./
